# Add many linear layout in to scroll view

Tags: android

I have some code like this:

```
l = new LinearLayout(this);
        l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        scrollView.addView(l);
        TextView ch = new TextView(this);
        Button ndda = new Button(this);
        ndda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        Button nddb = new Button(this);
        Button nddc = new Button(this);
        Button nddd = new Button(this);
        ch.setText("ndch");
        ndda.setText("da");
        nddb.setText("db");
        nddc.setText("dc");
        nddd.setText("dd");
        l.addView(ch);
        l.addView(ndda);
        l.addView(nddb);
        l.addView(nddc);
        l.addView(nddd);
```

now i want to add lot of linear layout( may be 15) in to scroll view. How can I do that with shortly code? and the Button in each linear layout i want to setOnClickListener on them to do some thing. I try to do this with listview but it's alway refresh when scroll, i can't disable refresh. I'm a newbie so pls show me detail. Thank for all

Comment: You might want to look into using a ListView instead.

Comment: You can have only one direct child of a ScrollView. If you want to do that then add it inside a main linear layout.

Comment: Yeah @MikeM. is right. From what I can get from this question I feel its better to use ListView or GridView instead.

Comment: As i said i try it with listview but listview alway refresh when scroll. i use view holder but get a new problem. Did u know how to disable that refresh? i just change the background of button when click on it but when i scroll it background return first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774470/fix-code-custom-listview

Answer (score 0):

Some guys already mentioned it before in the comments... use a ListView or even better ... a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Here's a good tutorial for the [RecylcerView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html).

Nevertheless a `ScrollView`can have only 1 child (in your case a `LinearLayout`), which again can contain multiple layouts within.