# How to correctly handle database in ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor, android-database

I am building a very simple app that contains a `SQLiteDatabase` which I want to display in a `ListFragment`, using a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

My code is working fine, but I'm not sure if I'm doing things the correct way. I have searched a lot for (authoritative) examples of this, but have only found either overly simplified examples using `ArrayAdapter`, or overly complicated examples using `ContentProvider`.

#### ListFragment

```
public class CallListFragment extends ListFragment{

    private CallListDbHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private CallListAdapter adapter;



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Create a database helper
        dbHelper = new CallListDbHelper(getActivity());

        // Get the database
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // Get a cursor to the entire call list from the database
        cursor = db.query(                                                          // SELECT
                CallEntry.TABLE_NAME,                                               // FROM ...
                new String[] {                                                      // <columns>
                        CallEntry._ID,
                        CallEntry.COLUMN_NUMBER,
                        CallEntry.COLUMN_TIME },
                null,                                                               // WHERE ... (x = ?, y = ?)
                null,                                                               //   <columnX, columnY>
                null,                                                               // GROUP BY ...
                null,                                                               // HAVING ...
                CallEntry.COLUMN_TIME + " DESC"                                     // ORDER BY ...
        );

        adapter = new CallListAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Close cursor, database and helper
        if( null !=cursor ) cursor.close();
        if( null != db ) db.close();
        if( null != dbHelper ) dbHelper.close();
    }

}
```

#### Adapter

```
public class CallListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {


    private static final String[] FROM = {
        CallListContract.CallEntry.COLUMN_NUMBER,
        CallListContract.CallEntry.COLUMN_TIME
    };

    private static final int[] TO = {
        R.id.phoneNumber,
        R.id.time
    };



    public CallListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        this(context, R.layout.listitem_call, cursor, FROM, TO);
    }


    private CallListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, the fragment looks good. CallListAdapter might be also interesting.

Comment: Have added the adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

For something simple it will work. But...

Do you use your DB in one place?

How big is your DB?

How often do you hit onResume/onPause?

General recommendation is onResume/onPause should be as fast as possible, but DB operations can be blocking...

Especially first touch (creation) of DB can be time-consuming and potentially you can get [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

Don't use Activity as a Context or you may can get memory leaks. The recommended way is to use the Context of your Application in conjunction with [singleton pattern](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html), so you'll not bother [to close DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608498/best-place-to-close-database-connection).

CursorLoader needs the cursor to be open in order to function and will call close() on the cursor for you. As for SimpleCursorAdapter I don't see auto-close feature in the source code =(.

Comment: Perhaps some example code to clarify what you mean by all that..?

Comment: I was under the impression that a `CursorLoader` requires a `ContentProvider`, which just seems waaaay to overkill for what I'm doing. They even say so in  [Creating a Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) (under "Before you start building).

Comment: @Maxim G are your sure with close() being called automatically? I don't remember it that way and i couldn't find andy references to this.

Comment: So I read the post on not needing to close the database. But, by "database" and "DB", it's not entirely clear if people mean the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, or the `SQLiteDatabase`? I'm guessing it's the former, because the latter can be opened either for reading or writing, so how would you make it into a singleton and never close it?

Comment: Edited answer, still need some tests.

Comment: @J.Dow For SimpleCursorAdapter I don't see auto-close feature in the source code.

Comment: @BadCash Neither SQLiteOpenHelper nor SQLiteDatabase should be closed. The whole application process will be cleaned by user exit.

Comment: How then should I open the database? For some queries I just need to read from  the database (i.e. `getReadableDatabase()`, and for others I need to write to it (i.e. `getWritableDatabase()`). Are you saying I should call `getWritableDatabase()` once, so that I can use both reading and writing after that? It sounds a bit sketchy...