# Closing DBHelper in Application class

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

With reference to [Android: Documentation for using SQLite database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite), we should be closing the reference to the DBHelper in the onDestroy of the activity :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mDbHelper.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

But I want to use the DBHelper object in the Application class :

```
public class UnifiedApplication extends Application {

    // Database helper
    public UnifiedAppDBHelper mDbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mDbHelper = new UnifiedAppDBHelper(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

I thought about adding the `mDbHelper.close()` in the `onTerminate()` of the Application class, but as mentioned in the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate()), `onTerminate()` will never be called on a production device. Where should I close the mDbHelper object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best place to close database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608498/best-place-to-close-database-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to close your `mDbHelper` object. Your database session will live as long as `Application` object lives and this is fine.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739454/759007) you can find more about it.