# Do I need to close Android Room Database?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm just getting to know about Android Room Database.

When I was using Realm Database, I had to care if Realm DB instance was opened or closed.
So I managed it by `.use` in my kotlin code.

```
RealmProvider(context).getDatabase().use { database ->
                if (database == null) {
                    it.onError(Exception("DataBase Open Error !"))
                } else {
                    database.executeTransaction { realm -> realm.insert(SomeData) }
                    it.onComplete()
                }
            }
```

However; in Room DB, no one use `roomDatabase.close()` in their codes.

So I'm wondering when Room DB is closed and opened and also when db instance is allocated and free on RAM memory.

Comment: Usually everyone create singleton instance of db, and i guess (im not super expert) it doesn't worth keep close and opening it.
Interesting question

Comment: I have looked into the Android Profiler and the memory usage is ranging in 120 MB to 150 MB after several oprations, also I wasn't closing the database, even then there was no some sort of memory leak.

Comment: Did you try by closing and reopening it?

Comment: @Dak28 yes, when I wanted to check the db size, I closed it then open. Except this case, I didn't close Room DB. I just wondered why I don't need to close Room DB compared to Realm DB.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739454/1090523 the system will handle the closing of the database connection when the app is closed. No leak will occur, and it is also more performant to keep a connection open and reuse it than to keep opening and closing connections.