# Primary key not returned correctly in sqlite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am creating an app to understand sqlite database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKM0A.png)

Whenever I click add button the name would be added in sqlite database

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DBHelper helper=new DBHelper(MainActivity.this, null, null, 1);
            EmployeeData data=new EmployeeData(1, etName.getText().toString());
            int id=helper.add(data);
            data.setId(id);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
```

EmployeeData just contains constructor and getters and setters for the arguments.

DBHelper code:

```
public int add(EmployeeData data){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(NAME, data.getName());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        String sql="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+NAME+" = "+"'"+data.getName()+"'";
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        int id;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ID));
        }else {
            id=-1;
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return id;
    }
```

Consider I am entering "Aditya" in the edit text, I am getting a toast message of 1.

But when I change the name as "Adity" I am still getting a toast message of 1.

Why isn't primary key of second record changing?

I even tried adding AUTOINCREMENT but it doesn't work.

What is the problem?

Btw the `1` in employee data constructor has no relation to the primary key

Database creation:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+NAME+" VARCHAR2(25))";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
```

Comment: show your database creation code

Comment: I have added it above

Comment: If you made changes to the definition of the table since you first ran the app, then uninstall the app from the device and rerun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method. It returns the id, as a long, of the inserted row else -1 if the row was not inserted.

- In theory the id can be a long, as such it is recommended that long instead of int is used.

Assuming that the id column is an alias of the `rowid`.

- according to your CREATE SQL it is.

Your code could be the simpler :-

```
public long add(EmployeeData data){
    long id;
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NAME, data.getName());
    id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    db.close();
    return id;
}
```

However, it is inefficient to close the database -

- close itself is not that inefficient, the inefficiency is opening the database again which is relatively expensive.
- This q/a has some details regarding this [Best place to close database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608498/best-place-to-close-database-connection)

I would suggest the even simpler :-

```
public long add(EmployeeData data) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NAME, data.getName());
    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

**Example**

Here's the code of an example based upon your code (using the logcat as well as the toast) :-

The DatabaseHelper **DBHelper**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DBNAME = "MYDB";
    public static int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
    public static String ID = "_id";
    public static String NAME = "_name";

    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+NAME+" VARCHAR2(25))";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    }

    public long add(EmployeeData data) {
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(NAME, data.getName());
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }
}
```

The invoking Activity

- the onClickListener has been replaced with direct invocation of 2 inserts
- in addition to using the toast the log has been used to record the id's inserted

:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DBHelper helper=new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        EmployeeData data=new EmployeeData(1, "TestIt");
        long id=helper.add(data);
        data.setId(id);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Long.toString(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("ADDEMP","ID of Employee was " + id);

        data.setName("TestAnother");
        data.setId(id =helper.add(data));
        Toast.makeText(this,Long.toString(id),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("ADDEMP","ID of Employee was " + id);
    }
}
```

The EmployeeData class (guessed) :-

```
public class EmployeeData {
    long id;
    String name;
    int something;

    EmployeeData(int something, String name) {
        this.id = -1;
        this.name = name;
        this.something = something;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSomething(int something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
}
```

**Results**

When the above is run after ensuring that no database already exists (the App is uninstalled from the test device (Emulator) via settings)

- Uninstalling the App deletes the database and should be undertaken if any changes to the schema have been made, otherwise those changes will not be applied (not entirely true as you could introduce code to make such changes).

The LogCat shows :-

```
D/ADDEMP: ID of Employee was 1
D/ADDEMP: ID of Employee was 2
```

If run a second time the LogCat shows :-

```
D/ADDEMP: ID of Employee was 3
D/ADDEMP: ID of Employee was 4
```

---

---

**Additional as per comments**

As per the comments you issue was that you were inadvertently using a temporary database/in_memory database and rows were being added to a new database each time and hence the id was always 1.

The following are some suggested changes (see comments in the code) based upon your GITHUB code.

**DBHelper**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "adityya425"; //<<<<<<<<<< SUGGESTED ADDITION
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    final String TABLE_NAME="Employee";
    final String ID="_id";
    final String NAME="name";

    /*

    <<<<<<<<<< Replaced constructor with simpler to use (only requires the Context to be passed to the helper)
    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, null, version);
    }
     */
    public  DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION); //<<<<<<<<<< only context is passed
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+NAME+" VARCHAR2(25))";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long add(EmployeeData data){
        long id;
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(NAME, data.getName());
        id=db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        //String sql="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+NAME+" = "+"'"+data.getName()+"'";
        //Cursor c=db.rawQuery(sql, null);

//        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
//            id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ID));
//        }else {
//            id=-1;
//        }
        return id;
    }

    /*
        <<<<<<<<<< NOT REQUIRED optional extra that will output all the existing rows to the log
        e.g.
        2021-03-23 18:21:01.749 4963-4963/a.a.adityya425 D/CURSORINFO: ID = 1 NAME = harry
        2021-03-23 18:21:01.749 4963-4963/a.a.adityya425 D/CURSORINFO: ID = 2 NAME = bert
     */
    public void showALL(Context context) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("CURSORINFO","ID = " + csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(ID)) + " NAME = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(NAME)));
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etName;
    Button btnAdd;
    DBHelper helper; //<<<<<<<<<< Single helper with class scope

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        helper = new DBHelper(this); //<<<<<<<< Instantiate Helper

        etName=findViewById(R.id.etName);
        btnAdd=findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //DBHelper helper=new DBHelper(MainActivity.this, "mydb", null, 1); <<<<<<<<<< REMOVED (no need)
            EmployeeData data=new EmployeeData(etName.getText().toString());
            long id=helper.add(data);
            data.setId(id);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Long.toString(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            helper.showALL(MainActivity.this); //<<<<<<<<<< Optional (logcat is available longer)
        });
    }
}
```

**Testing**

The App was run and 3 Employees were added (Fred, Mary and Susan). The logcat shows :-

```
2021-03-23 18:40:15.495 5642-5642/a.a.adityya425 D/CURSORINFO: ID = 1 NAME = Fred

2021-03-23 18:40:22.964 5642-5642/a.a.adityya425 D/CURSORINFO: ID = 1 NAME = Fred
2021-03-23 18:40:22.964 5642-5642/a.a.adityya425 D/CURSORINFO: ID = 2 NAME = Mary

2021-03-23 18:40:29.643 5642-5642/a.a.adityya425 D/CURSORINFO: ID = 1 NAME = Fred
2021-03-23 18:40:29.643 5642-5642/a.a.adityya425 D/CURSORINFO: ID = 2 NAME = Mary
2021-03-23 18:40:29.643 5642-5642/a.a.adityya425 D/CURSORINFO: ID = 3 NAME = Susan
```

Comment: This is working but any idea why my code wasn't working?

Comment: Your version is same as mine but still not working. Here is the code:https://github.com/Aditya425/sqlite-demo

Comment: @ADITYADIXIT OK basically you have inadvertently used an in memory database because the database name passed is **null**. The quick BUT NOT VERY GOOD fix is to pass a database name e.g. `DBHelper helper=new DBHelper(MainActivity.this, "mydb", null, 1);`. See how in my helper the database name is a constant (and only the context is passed to the database helper). I will add suggested changes to your code to the question (in due course).

Comment: I got the issue, I explicitly passed 1 always whenever I initialized the `DBHelper` class.

Comment: My doubt is whether I was creating a new table everytime I was creating a `DBHelper` object

Comment: @ADITYADIXIT more so, you were creating a new **database** each time (*and hence a new table as the new Database was empty when created*). P.S. the **1** (database version number) doesn't matter *(if you changed it to 2 as `onUpgrade` is empty all would do is increase the version number in the database which is part of the file)*. It is that you didn't supply a database name and thus the database was temporary each time you created a new helper object. (if the database is named it exists as a file (except for first ever run) so the helper opens the file/database).

Comment: @ADITYADIXIT P.S. if the answer (or other answers) helped you please tick the answer to show that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used in **SQLlite** when I needed the new auto incremented primary key:

```
 int getId(){
    ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (rs.next()) {
        id = rs.getLong(1);
        return id;
    }
}
```

where statement is a *PreparedStatement*

Comment: I have to read about `ResultSet` and `statement.getGeneratedKeys();` but why isn't my code working?

Comment: TBH, I have never worked with SQLlite in the way you do, so I dont really know.

Comment: Oh, What I am doing is querying the current added record and getting the primary key from it. This works in sql language but not here don't know why

Comment: hmm, but where is the *insert* executed? I dont really understand the code

Comment: In `db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);;`

Comment: hmm, and maybe when it is autoincremented, it is not included in the select all, because it is probably not in the create table statement as well. But I might be completely wrong here.

Comment: oh, I see it is in the create statement. But I meant insert

Comment: So if it is not in the insert, it might not be in the select * but I might be absolutely wrong

Comment: Since I have written `SELECT *` then everything for current record will be fetched

Comment: I dont know really. Maybe you should try to use the result set thing. Basically you put your string with sql statement to prepare statement and then execute query. The result is the result set and from that you get the generated keys as I showed above.

Comment: `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is where the primary key exists. ID is just a final string containing "id".